# gvfsd-dav process

Tags: gvfs

What is the process gvfsd-dav. 
The best I could find on my system monitor was that it is somehow associated to nautilus. I closed all the nautilus instances and still there are 2 instances of gvfsd-dav that are completely occupying 2 out of 4 CPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gvfsd is the daemon process for the GNOME Virtual File System ([gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS)). gvfsd-dav handels remote filesystemes ([WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV)). Are you using something like UbuntuOne?
If you mount such devices via nautilus you'll probably create these processes..

Comment: damn webDAV. It isn't UbuntuOne it's the damn interface to my website. Thanks.